# Как создать нормальную и удобную структуру таблиц в mysql

Tags: mysql, база-данных, структуры-данных

На сервисе есть несколько сущностей: блогеры, клиенты, проекты, менеджеры

---

У всех есть связка многие ко многим, но она работает не корректно

К примеру, при редактировании сущности **блогер**, мы можем задать несколько менеджеров, клиентов и проектов

Проблема в том, что я не понимаю как мне обновить в таблице связь **клиент-менеджер**, ведь когда его меняю нужно ещё указать для какого проекта (то есть к каким проектам связаны менеджер и клиент)

От куда брать id проекта, тоже не понимаю, ведь в сущности блогера подтягиваются только те проекты, которые связаны именно с блогером (а у блогера, клиента и менеджера могут быть разные проекты)

---

**Воронка работает так:** открывается проект и в нём ведётся блогеры, таблица `node_project_blogger`

Все связи находятся в таблице с префиксом `node_`

**[Дамп БД тут](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/YHyu_odcH4yRmA)**

**Вопрос:** Как мне сделать нормальную и удобную структуру таблиц?

Comment: Где выполненный анализ предметной области? Простого описания - катастрофически мало, чтобы определить, какие связи должны быть установлены и, соответственно, какие связующие таблицы созданы.

Comment: Где можно посмотреть \ почитать по БД именно связки многие ко многие?
Например как сервисы различные делают, чтобы понимать их строение